# Which R `arima` package is considered being the best?

Tags: r, arima

Which R's package with `arima` modeling capabilities is considered being the best ? I would like to simulate new time series from fitted `arima` model in straightforward way ?

Comment: Are you interested in univariate or multivariate modelling? And what exactly do you mean by simulate? Do you want to fit ARIMA to an existing time series or generate residuals that are the result of an ARIMA process?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like rugarch package. It gives a lot of  possibilities and models, easiness of use, maybe It's a bit too "black box".

```
  #example ARMA GARCH 1,1 need rugarch package
spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH",  garchOrder = c(1, 1)),mean.model     = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1)))

garch <- ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = timeseries)
forc<-ugarchforecast(garch,n.ahead=200)

plot(forc@forecast$sigmaFor)
plot(forc@forecast$seriesFor)
```

Comment: Is there a package which allows for estimation of non-consecutive lags, for example, to estimate only 1 nad 7 autoregressive lags ?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, I don't know any package like that